# jQuery ajax() vs get()/post()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I want to execute a PHP script. Which way is better?

This:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "php-script.php",
    dataType: "script"
});
```

Or this:

```
$.get("php-script.php", function(data) { });
```

Comment: What are the effects of the script?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In this case, I'd say `$.get`, as it's immediately clear what the type of request is. At any rate, it's just shorthand for the larger and more option-ified ajax call, and converting between the two is trivial in the worst case.

If you think that you'll need fancy `$.ajax` options, use `$.ajax`. If you don't use the convenience methods jQuery provides, such as `.load`, `$.get`, etc.

Answer (score 23):

`$.get()` is just a shortcut for an `$.ajax()` call of type "GET".

To Elaborate `$.get()` just calls `$.ajax()` in the background. Its a shortcut kind of like what `$(function(){})` is to `$(document).ready(function(){})`. Common use cases for `$.get` is for a quick and simple get, `$.ajax` should be used if you need to do something a bit more complex or if you need the extra flexibility.

Comment: $.get wraps $.ajax with type="GET". It's more than just a shortcut, the key difference being you can't make a POST request to the server using $.get.

Comment: uhh i would have thought that obvious... i have updated it since you think its not.

Comment: @Darko Z - no it did not seem obvious from your answer, that's why I commented - to point that out. Your update, however, does make it obvious.

Answer (score 2):

`$.get()`/`$.post()` don't support `beforeSend` like `$.ajax()` does. So you can't for example display a spinner while loading directly. But you can do this with [`.ajaxStart()`](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/).