# ajax vs get in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery ajax() vs get()/post()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344303/jquery-ajax-vs-get-post)

what is the difference between jQuery ajax() and jQuery get() ?
which one is better to load some data from a url in a div when user clicks on a link?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is **neither**. If you want to load HTML directly into a div, the simplest way is to use [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
jQuery('#divID').load(url);
```

It doesn't get any easier than that.

Comment: Very good point as long as the `<div>` element  doesn't contain any content (or it should be overwritten).

Answer (score 7):

From the docs for the [`jQuery.get()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) method.

*This is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:*

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Comment: @hd: Yes, `$.get` is just a wrapper for that `$.ajax` call. Just a convenience.

Answer (score 5):

`get` is just a shorthand to `ajax` (a wrapper with some predefined properties). So use the one more handy **for you** in this particular case.

Answer (score 4):

From the [jQuery manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)  `jQuery.get()` is equivalent to

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

In other words, `get()` is just a higher level alternative.